# Is there a way to remove default headers from HTTP Requests in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter

I have a test plan in JMeter, and I need to do a SOAP Request to a third-party API (NetSuite). The payload I'm using works perfectly when I try with SoapUI or even Postman, but when I try with JMeter it returns an HTML error page with status 206 (Partial Content) and this message: "An unexpected error has occurred. Please go back and try again".

As the error doesn't say much, I'm not sure why this is happening. I tried a lot of things but always get the same.

I know it could sound crazy, but my guess is that the header 'Content-Length' is causing this issue because when I add this header in Postman the API returns an error (not the same, but it fails).

As I don't have many options to resolve this, I really would like to test without that header, but I don't know if it's possible to remove the header once JMeter adds that automatically.

I will appreciate every help or ideas about that, thanks.

Comment: Can you try to ad this suspicious header to request from Postman or other tools? Do you try curl -v?

Comment: See https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-ws-test-plan.html

Answer (score 0):

If you can execute request successfully in SoapUI or Postman you can just record it using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder):

1. Prepare JMeter for recording. The fastest and the easiest way is using [JMeter Templates feature](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-save-%E2%80%98loads%E2%80%99-time-using-jmeters-template-feature)

   - From JMeter's Main Menu choose `File -> Templates -> Recording` and click "Create"
   - Switch to the `HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder` and click "Start"

     [image: JMeter Recording]
2. Prepare SoapUI for recording.

   - From SoapUI Main Menu choose `File -> Preferences -> Proxy Settings`
   - Click `Manual` and use `localhost` as "Host" and `8888` as "Port"

     [image: SoapUI for JMeter Proxy]
3. Run your request in SoapUI - JMeter will record it along with all necessary headers.